# Spring Security not allowing $.ajax() post request

Tags: ajax

I have implemented Spring Security with form-login to invoke restful services and its working well. But when I try to send a `$.ajax()` post request within any of my jsp pages, I get an error message

```
"WARN: org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported".
```

The same method in controller is executed if its `GET` request from jquery but it if POST then spring doesn't allow it.

Comment: I too have the same problem did you manage to solve it